# Insertion text box into custom Telerik Kendo Filter

Tags: text, filter, kendo-ui, telerik

I want to create a Custom Filter for Ages of the Patients (their age can be in years, months and days). The code is:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<RunSummary>()
          .Name("Runs")
          .DataSource(datasource => datasource
                .Ajax().PageSize(25)        
                .Sort(sort => sort.Add("TimeOn").Descending())                        
                .Read(read => read.Action("GetRunSummaries", "Home")))
          .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(d => d.RunId).Title("").Width(30).Filterable(false)
                        .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' unlock='true' class='primaryBox' id='#= RunId #' />").Visible(User.IsInRole("Registry Administrator"));

                  columns.Bound(c => c.UniqueId).Title(ELSORegistry.Resources.Views.Home.HomeStrings.UniqueId);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.RunNo).Title(SharedStrings.Run);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.Birthdate).Title(SharedStrings.Birthdate).Format("{0:g}").Filterable(true);

                  //columns.Bound(c => c.Age).Title(SharedStrings.Age).ClientTemplate("#= formatAge(Age)#");
                  columns.Bound(c => c.Age).Title(SharedStrings.Age)
                        .ClientTemplate("#= formatAge(Age)#")
                        .Filterable(
                            filterable => filterable
                                .UI("cityFilter")
                                .Extra(false)                                
                                .Operators(operators => operators
                                    .ForNumber(str => str.Clear().IsEqualTo("Is equal to").IsGreaterThan("Is greater than").IsLessThan("Is less than"))

                                    )

                      );
                  columns.Bound(c => c.TimeOn).Title(PatientStrings.TimeOn)
                      .Format("{0:g}")
                      .Filterable(true);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.TimeOff).Title(PatientStrings.TimeOff)
                      .Format("{0:g}")
                      .Filterable(true);

                  columns.Bound(c => c.isLocked).Title("Locked").ClientTemplate("#= isLocked ? 'Yes' : 'No' #");

                  //columns.Bound(p => p.Abbreviation).Title("Mode");
                  columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Patient").Click("selectPatient"));
                  columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Run").Click("selectRun"));
              }
          )
          .Pageable(p => p.PageSizes(new[] {10, 25, 50, 100}))
          .Sortable()
          .Filterable( )
          .Events( e => e.FilterMenuInit("FilterMenuFunc") ) // apply x [closing box] on pop up filter box
          )
</section>

<script>

    function cityFilter(element) {
            element.kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: [{ Name: "Days", Value: "1" }, { Name: "Months", Value: "2" }, { Name: "Years", Value: "3" }]
            , dataTextField: "Name"
            , dataValueField: "Value"
                        });
                    window.setTimeout(function () {
            element.data("kendoDropDownList").value("3");
        }, 1);
    }
</script>
```

I have to insert a text box into Age filter, to put here number (of Ages). How to insert text box field into the Custom Filter? Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible solution is:

```
function AgeFilter(element) {

        element.kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: [{ Name: "Days", Value: "1" }, { Name: "Months", Value: "2" }, { Name: "Years", Value: "3" }]
            , dataTextField: "Name"
            , dataValueField: "Value"
        });

        window.setTimeout(function () {
            element.data("kendoDropDownList").value("1");
        }, 1);
```

and in the grid:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.customAge).Title(SharedStrings.Age)
                         .Filterable(
                             filterable => filterable
                                 .UI("AgeFilter")
                                 .Extra(false)
                                 .Operators(operators => operators
                                     .ForString(str => str.Clear().IsEqualTo("Is equal to"))
                                     )

                       );

        }
```